# In visual studio how to select word in text editor using keyboard

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

In earlier version of  Microsoft Visual Studio products if user in text editor hit CTRL+W editor will do select the word where is pointer. Does that keyboard shortcut exists still in Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: I Visual Studio 2017 Community ed. it is (again?) `Ctrl+W`. I strongly believe it is by default. (At least, I did not set it.)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

In Tools | Options | Environment | Keyboard enter "Word" into "Show commands containing" and see all commands associated with words.

Here the command `Edit.SelectCurrentWord` is assigned to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>, but your setup might be different. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> is another common setting.

Answer (score 14):

When using Resharper 'Shift + Ctrl + W' shortcut may be overriden and not working. Create new shortcut for Edit.SelectCurrentWord as 'Ctrl + W, Ctrl + W'. It works fine so you may use this and resharper shortcuts.

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio 2019/2022 the default keypress to select a word is:

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The path i have to use is Debbugen (Debug), Optionen... (Options), Umgebung (Environment), Tastatur (Keyboard) and the first menu to expand to chose (Standard)([maybe]default).

I have no defined version control.
With version
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.10.1

Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.04.084