# How can I select a word on Visual Studio 2017 with a shortcut

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, keyboard-shortcuts

I remember I can do that in the previous version of Visual Studio, but now I can select a word using a shortcut. It helps me to be more productive.

My Keyboard setting looks ok, but the shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> doesn't work.

> [image]

I have Resharper (version 2018.1) installed, but it doesn't look is affecting the shortcut:

> [image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In visual studio how to select word in text editor using keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433730/in-visual-studio-how-to-select-word-in-text-editor-using-keyboard)

Comment: The shortcut is `Ctrl + W`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it doesn't work for VS 2017

Comment: Try Ctrl+Shift+W then. As the duplicate explains, you can find all keyboard shortucts from Options, Keyboard. The relevant command is `Edit.SelectCurrentWord`. Some program like Resharper may have changed it

Comment: I've tried `Ctrl+Shift+W`, `Ctrl+W` and it doesn't work. Also, I tried to change the value of `Edit.SelectCurrentWord` on Keyboard setting, but it still failed.

Comment: What was the original value? Do you havew anything else installed, eg Resharper or another tool? You can always *reset* the shortcuts to their original values

Comment: The original value is `Ctrl+Shift+W`. I have ReSharper installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't know what happened to my Visual Studio, but to solve this problem I had to go to Tools > Options > Keyboard and chose all the keyboard mapping scheme and made sure the command was set correctly. After that, the command <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> starts to work.

[image]

I hope it can help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>

Comment: For some reason that I don't know, it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2017 15.7.6, the shortcut is: `Ctrl + W`.
Here's a link that I've found it useful which list all Visual Studio 2017 shortcuts [Visual Studio shortcuts](http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2017/)